# how to create one activity with changing data?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a listView, and each item in this listview should lead to an activity , all those activities have the same structure i wannna change just the text and pictures for each one ! is there anyway to do that?

```
public class SaladsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);
    ArrayList<Product> prod= new ArrayList<Product>();

    prod.add(new Product(R.drawable.sa1,"Mini Salad","1.5 $","more"));
    prod.add(new Product(R.drawable.sa2,"Salade Pêcheur","1.5 $","more"));
    prod.add(new Product(R.drawable.sa3,"Salade Italienne","1.5 $","more"));
    prod.add(new Product(R.drawable.sa4,"Salade César","1.5 $","more"));



    TypeProducts itemsAdapter = new TypeProducts(this,  prod);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    list.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==0){
                Intent prod = new Intent(ProductsActivity.this, A.class);
                startActivity(prod);
            }
            if(position==1){
                Intent prod = newIntent(ProductsActivity.this,B.class);
                startActivity(prod);
            }
            if(position==2){

                Intent prod = new Intent(ProductsActivity.this, C.class);
                startActivity(prod);
            }
            if(position==3){
                Intent prod = new Intent(ProductsActivity.this, D.class);
                startActivity(prod);
            }
    });

}
}
```

I dont wanna create A,B,C,D Activities i wanna create just one but it will depend on each item!

Comment: yes, there is. show some code and we will help you master it

Comment: ok i've just edited it

Comment: use `putExtra` (`Intent`s method) with values you want to pass and `getIntent().getExtras().get...` in called `Activity`s `onCreate`. edit: check out (not mine) answer :) good luck!

Comment: Why not send an argument via Intent Extras?

Comment: i just started a few days ago learning about apps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Intent you can do this. Like Following:

```
        listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        listViewArrayAdapter=new ListViewArrayAdapter(this,listviewArrayList);// set data for your arraylist (listviewArrayList) before using it here
        listview.setAdapter(listViewArrayAdapter);


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("yourTextId",listviewArrayList.get(position).getYourText);
                bundle.putInt("dataImg", listviewArrayList.get(position).getImageId());


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SeconActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

And inside SecondActivity something like this.

```
String text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("yourTextId");
int imageId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("dataImg");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Intent` to transfer data from one `Activity` to another:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "some data for this key");
startActivity(intent);
```

And then to get this data back use `getIntent().getExtras().getString(...)` method in `SecondActivity`:

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

So the final code could be:

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view_id);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            String selectedText = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            // pass selectedText to Intent
            ...
        }
});
```

And then get it in `SecondActivity` and process it somehow (e. g. change text depending on selected item).